# Persistent Virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm running an application in the virtual environment onte via the terminal using the command, python file.py (which probably opens a session) and activates the application's operation. The problem is that when I close the session or close the terminal the application stops working, there is the possibility of making virtualenv persistent, always leaving it active regardless of closing the terminal window and without the possibility of restarting virtualenv (auto restart) when the code changes ?

Comment: What sense would the virtual envs have then? Have you actually understood its purpose?

Comment: It is normal if you close the terminal that the application stops as well.

Comment: Virtualenv serves to isolate the python version and can install a newer one where it is possible to start applications. So far so good, but how much does the solution remain activated ?

Comment: Are you shelling into a system that supports `tmux`? It will allow you to keep a shell active and exit the session only to come back to it at a later time via `tmux attach`.